# Undefined mixin

Tags: css, sass, compiler-errors

I'm using SASS to style a landing page but I am getting an error when I try to compile my sass into CSS.  I receive an error that reads

> error sass/modules/_buttons.sass (Line 11: Undefined mixin
>   'button-size'.)

Here is the code for this particular part

`.btn
  display: inline-block
  font-weight: $font-weight-normal
  line-height: $base-line-height
  text-align: center
  font-size: $font-base
  vertical-align: middle
  border: $border-width solid transparent
  transition: $btn-transition
  border-radius: $border-radius
  +button-size($btn-padding-y, $btn-padding-x, $font-base, $border-radius)` <-- Line 11

and the actual mixin code is

```
=button-size($btn-padding-y, $btn-padding-x, $font-base, $border-radius)
  padding: $btn-padding-y $btn-padding-x
  font-size: $font-base
  border-radius: $border-radius
```

Comment: do you have the [@include] or [@mixin] line somewhere referencing the definition or defining the mixin? https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin ... (ignore the brackets I don't know how to make a comment realize I am not trying to @ a user and didn't see it in the help doc for comments.)

Comment: Are you sure that your mixin is declared before you call it?

Answer (score 1):

hi if you have the same problem, you have to import your mixin first in your main.scss

```
1. import 'utils/mixin' //contain all of my mixin
2. import 'other/css-thing'... //call the mixin above
```

the mixin can't be write below in the main.scss