# scss using mixins and media-Undefined mixin

Tags: reactjs, scss-mixins

I am using mixins and media for first time and my css skills aren't that great either. Its used in React app. I am getting SassError: Undefined mixin. Error on this piece of code and not sure what I am missing here.  Is there any library I need to bring in?

In my map.tsx file I am importing scss file and using the div tag

```
import styles from "./map.module.scss";
<div className={styles.helpbutton}>
    <AboutPopup />
  </div>
```

In my map.module.scss I have this css

```
.helpbutton {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  @include for-phone-only {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    right: 2em;
  }
}


@mixin for-phone-only {  // Seems like error is coming here
  @media (max-width: 599px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

But I am getting this error SassError: Undefined mixin.

Not sure why is it saying its undefined when it is right there in the same file.

Comment: The defined `@mixin`, I guess, it should be loaded before the actual `@import`.

Comment: Thanks MarkBurns, yes I figured that its something to do with the order and after placing the @maxin before the use, it seems to be working but I couldn't find any documentation on this as to what the best way to do it is and why does the order matter.

Comment: i got the same issues but i found the solution [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64319884/13800003)